# animateWithDuration is not showing

Tags: swift, animation, uiview

I'm learning Swift and I'm having problems moving a UIView from different functions. If I use this:

ViewController:

```
let boardView = BoardView()

@IBAction func startButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    view.addSubview(boardView.background)
}
```

The class BoardView:

```
class BoardView : UIView {

   let multiplier: CGFloat = 0.95
   let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

   var background: UIView {
      let boardSize: CGFloat = multiplier * screenSize.width
      let board = UIView(
         frame: CGRectMake(-boardSize,
         screenSize.height / 2 - boardSize / 2,
         boardSize,
         boardSize)
      )

       board.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
       board.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
       UIView.animateWithDuration(0.15, animations: {
          board.center.x = self.screenSize.width / 2
      })
      return board
   }
}
```

The animation works (in an counterintuitive way, for me). If I try to move the UIView from another function, like this:

ViewController button:

```
@IBAction func startButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    view.addSubview(boardView.background)
    boardView.moveBackground()
}
```

BoardView:

```
class BoardView : UIView {

let multiplier: CGFloat = 0.95
let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

var background: UIView {
    let boardSize: CGFloat = multiplier * screenSize.width
    let board = UIView(
        frame: CGRectMake(-boardSize,
        screenSize.height / 2 - boardSize / 2,
        boardSize,
        boardSize))

    board.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
    board.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    return board
}

func moveBackground() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.15, animations: {
        self.background.center.x = self.screenSize.width / 2
    })
 }
}
```

The animation doesn't work. Nothing happens either if I use `animateWithDuration` in the ViewController.

How can I move an UIView from a different place than where I've created it?

Comment: The names for your class and variables are really confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code, while strangely working, is in fact poorly defined behavior. You should not start animating a view before adding it to the view hierarchy. You're getting away with it but don't do that.

In your second approach, which is closer to correct, the problem is that you've made `background` a non-lazy computed property. So every time you call `model.background`, you get a different object.

Given how you've written this, a `lazy` property for background is probably what you really mean.

As @dasdom notes, `BoardModel` is a very bad name for a view. This should be `BoardView`.

In general, your flow is a bit strange. I would probably have the `BoardView` add the background to itself. If the controller is actually adding the background to some other view (other than `BoardView`) then that's *really* bizarre, and you need to rethink your code structure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But Xcode notifies me about the error: "'lazy' may not be used on a computed property" when I try to add it

Comment: Do you mean using the `addSubview` into a function in `Boardview`? I feel like I have to save the background in a non local variable so I can move it from a different function

Comment: Ok, I fixed it using a function called `setBackground()` and `lazy var background: UIView = self.setBackground()`. I still don't know if it's weird adding the view in the controller

Answer (score 0):

When ever you access the `background` of the `boardModel` (which is a really bad name for a view!), a new view is created and returned. I don't think this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @dasdom. I'm not surprised it's a bad name. If I'm right in any other names for variables is pretty much coincidence. I'm so new at object oriented programming. I would appreciate your suggestion for a name for this UIView.

Comment: What about boardView?